# Python Numpy - Create 2d array where length is based on 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Sorry for confusing title, but not sure how to make it more concise. Here's my requirements:

```
arr1 = np.array([3,5,9,1])
arr2 = ?(arr1)
```

arr2 would then be:

```
[
[0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

It doesn't need to vary based on the max, the shape is known in advance. So to start I've been able to get a shape of zeros:

```
arr2 = np.zeros((len(arr1),max_len))
```

And then of course I could do a for loop over arr1 like this:

```
for i, element in enumerate(arr1):
    arr2[i,0:element] = np.arange(element)
```

but that would likely take a long time and both dimensions here are rather large (arr1 is a few million rows, max_len is around 500). Is there a clean optimized way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Can you create a 'mask' by doing some sort of 'outer' operation on `np.arange(10)` with `arr1`?  Something that is `True` where the sequence is <= `arr1`?

Answer (score 2):

Building on  a 'padding' idea posted by @Divakar some years ago:

```
In [161]: res = np.arange(9)[None,:].repeat(4,0)
In [162]: res[res>=arr1[:,None]] = 0
In [163]: res
Out[163]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `itertools.zip_longest` -

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

l = map(range, arr1)
arr2 = np.column_stack((itertools.zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=0)))
print(arr2)
```

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: `zip_longest` is a good tool for 'padding' lsts or arrays.  While there's a clever way of padding with array 'masking', this itertools is easier to remember and apply.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a slight variation on @hpaulj's answer because you mentioned that `max_len` is around `500` and you have millions of rows. In this case, you can precompute a 500 by 500 matrix containing all possible rows and index into it using `arr1`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

max_len = 500
arr = np.random.randint(0, max_len, size=10**5)

# generate all unique rows first, then index
# can be faster if max_len << len(arr)
# 53 ms
template = np.tril(np.arange(max_len)[None,:].repeat(max_len,0), k=-1)
res = template[arr,:]

# 173 ms
res1 = np.arange(max_len)[None,:].repeat(arr.size,0)
res1[res1>=arr[:,None]] = 0

assert (res == res1).all()
```